# Adding jQuery in Joomla's2.5 article

Tags: jquery, css, joomla

Basically, I want something similair to this : http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/tryit.asp?filename=tryjquery_slide_down .
A toggle slide effect using jQuery in an article.
The CSS isn't a problem since I can add it in my template.css file, however, I'm bit confused about where can I put the jQuery code.
Do you guys have some ideas ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The JavaScript would go in your Joomla template file, just ftp to:

yoursite.com/templates/your_template/index.php

You can also get your to template files via Joomla Administrator then click on Template Manager under the Extension Manager.

Just copy the JavaScript into the head of the template index.php file.

The JQuery should load with Joomla core.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah that's what I've done in the first place, but it seems like I've missed one of the '$' to change it with 'jQuery'.
Now it's working just fine.

But now the jQuery portion is loaded in all pages, so I've done this.

The article code

```
<div class="myArticle">
<div id="flip">Click to slide the panel down or up</div>
<div id="panel">Hello world!</div>
<div id="flip2">Click to slide the panel down or up</div>
<div id="panel2">Hello world!</div>
</div>
```

And the jQuery code

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
jQuery(".myArticle div").click(function(){
jQuery("#" + jQuery(this).attr("id") + '+div').slideToggle("slow");
});
});
```

But doing so still loads the code everywhere, so I had to add this

```
<?php if(basename($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']) == "ThePageIWant") { ?>
  /* jQuery code */
<?php } ?>
```

I can see from the veiw source code that the jQuery portion is only loaded in the article I want.

Is this Okay ? or there is a Joomla way ?